# Can I sue the producer and/or the state TV for not acknowledging me?

Tags: acknowledgement

When I was a child I turned on the TV and decided to watch cartoons. I found out *Pat and Mat* has not been on the conductor for a while. So I called the call center of the state broadcast. I didn't know the name of the animation series at those times, except for an old name, *That's it*. So I told the operator: "Please broadcast "That's it". It is a beautiful cartoon with two foolish characters." Also I gave my name and last name to him.

The operator didn't understand which cartoon I'm talking about. So he replied to me: "I'm telling this to higher staff. They will show it for you to watch." Then he said bye and hung up the phone.

Some months later, I was watching the TV and the children's program presenter said: "There will be a new children's TV series called "That's it". It is now being produced and will come soon."

However, the first episode of the series got aired. But I didn't see my name nor in the opening neither the closing theme as the person who got the idea of making it.

**My question**: Now that about 20 years have been passed can I sue the producer of the series an/or the state TV for not acknowledging me?

Comment: It wasn't your own original name – it was the name of an old show. *"I'm telling this to higher staff. They will show it for you to watch."* You might have believed that as a child, but do you still?

Comment: But they made a new series using that name.

Comment: I think you said that they made a previous series of that name. Now think about this... suppose 20,000 viewers had requested "That's it" to be back. Do you think they would have credited all your names?

Comment: And what if I'm the only one?

Comment: The *That's it* that was the other name of *Pat and Mat* (what I asked for)  has nothing to do with this *That's it* that was made in my childhood. Different characters, different story, etc.

Comment: It's still not an original name. It was their name, not yours. Anyway you would need a record of the conversation – if they still have it after 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

Let’s assume the most generous interpretation: you came up with a fully fleshed-out idea for a television show - name, characters, plot, scene-setting - the lot. You told this idea over the phone to someone else who made this show incorporating every single part of your idea.

Here’s the rub: **nobody owns ideas**.

Unless you had them sign a non-disclosure agreement before you told them (which you didn’t), they are free to use your ideas however they like.